# UserRole IN SOQL

Tags: soql

We have unique requirement where we want user role too in our below query.

```
SELECT PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.IsCustom, PermissionSet.Label, 
PermissionSet.PermissionsApiEnabled, Assignee.Name, Assignee.Id, Assignee.Profile.Name, 
Assignee.ProfileId,Assignee.Profile.UserType, SystemModstamp, Assignee.isActive
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
Where Assignee.isActive = True AND permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE
ORDER BY Assignee.Name
```

We are unable to query and get the user role from above query can anyone help here.

Thanks
Pushpesh

Comment: I ran your query in my dev org and didn't get the results. Seems that the conditions in the where clause `Assignee.isActive = True AND permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE` are not met. When I removed this `permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE`, the query returned 6 rows. So you indeed don't have records in your database that satisfy these conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Assignee is user. So simply query UserRoleId and UserRole.Name in query like below:

> SELECT PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.IsCustom,
>   PermissionSet.Label,  PermissionSet.PermissionsApiEnabled,
>   Assignee.Name, Assignee.Id, Assignee.Profile.Name, 
>   Assignee.ProfileId, Assignee.UserRoleId, Assignee.UserRole.Name,Assignee.Profile.UserType,
>   SystemModstamp, Assignee.isActive FROM PermissionSetAssignment  Where
>   Assignee.isActive = True AND permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE
>   ORDER BY Assignee.Name